# How to attach the visual studio projects to debug by using AttachedToProcess

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have two instance of Visual studio 2010.

1. In first visual studio I have sample attached to dll.
2. In Second visual studio I have source for the dll, attached in above mentioned sample.

how do I debug the source using attachToProcess in the visual Studio instance. I have tried some others from sites. but those are not helpful. I have faced ***"breakpoint in source is unable to hit".***

Comment: have you correct pdb files copyied with the dll-files?

Comment: pdb files may not be referred properly

Comment: yes pdb files are correctly copied with dlls

Comment: Help to attach the dlls still I m not getting this

Answer (score 0):

You just have to open the file in first visual studio which you want to debug of dll and put breakpoint on that file.